# How Will I get the Present date is 1st of the Month in C#

Tags: c#

Could you please help me,

How Will I get to know "Present date is 1st of the Month" in C#.
I am writing Batch Job (Which runs on every day mid night 12 AM) in C#, here I am doing some logic , If the present date is 1st Of the Month.
Kindly help me.

Comment: why no to check if current day is 1st?
` if DateTime.Now.Day == 1`

Comment: If you run it at midnight you have a high chance of missing "today", whatever your definition of that is. Why don't you set the Batch Job to only run on the first day of the month?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, we have only 1 Batch Job, which runs on every day 12AM, here only I need include the logic If the present date is 1st of the Month

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [`DateTime.Day`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.day%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

> Gets the day of the month represented by this instance.

So, in your code just test:

```
if(DateTime.Today.Day == 1)
{
    // Today is the first of the month
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response :)

Answer (score 2):

To check if the current date is the 1st of the month, you could do something like this:

```
var today = DateTime.Now;
if(today.Day == 1) 
{ 
  // ... run your batch job
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the current date for it's day property

```
if (DateTime.UtcNow.Day == 1) {
    DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response :)